# Are junk DNA's mb also counted when it is stated that human DNA contains 3mb?

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics

The human DNA molecule (chromosome) is about 2 meters in length. See [here](https://www.sciencefocus.com/the-human-body/how-long-is-your-dna/). We have 46 of them so in total 92 meters (imagine we would place all our DNA in a row...)

In [this](https://www.quora.com/Which-animal-has-the-longest-genomic-DNA) article it is said that the Protopterus Aethiopicus (a.k.a The marbled lungfish) has the most base pairs (about 133mb vs about 3mb of the human genome) of all living beings (flora and fauna) residing in the DNA of its cells.

That's a huge difference! That's why I ask if junk mbs are accounted for too in the 3mb in human DNA.

Comment: Some notes and suggestions: 1) A diploid human genome is ~6.4 megabases in length — bases are not bits. 2) The relationship between DNA bases and genes is similar to that between letters and sentences — you will get a better response if your questions don't conflate these concepts. 3) Please don't refer to "junk DNA" — this is a misleading and inaccurate term. 4) You won't find a (reliable) source for your claim that human DNA contains the most "junk" because it isn't true! ——— I encourage you to make the time to understand the basics of genetics and molecular biology. ...

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. There are also online platforms called MOOCs that offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two that I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Comment: @tyersome Information is measured in bits (or bytes). Not in bases. Well, you can assign one bit to one base, but basically this is the same. Do you have a source that my claim is not true? I referred to junk DNA as non-coding DNA. Just read! Thank you very much.

Comment: DNA is a molecule — the size you quoted is a length (in base pairs) not a measure of information content. The information content of a sequence that contains highly repetitive regions (like a human chromosome) is not equal to the sequences length and since DNA contains four bases it certainly is no way "basically the same"!

Comment: Well, anyway, this is not a question of what the unit of information is!

Comment: @tyersome Can you prove my claim wrong? After all, you say it's NOT true.

Comment: BTW: It is not called junk DNA, it is called non-coding DNA.

Comment: And? What do you want to tell me with this comment? Non-coding and junk is distinctively different. One doesn't code for proteins but contains a lot of regulatory (for example) information, the other one implies that it can be removed which it cannot. The term "junk" has no scientific basis.

Comment: That means the more non-coding DNA, the more complex the species. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: I have edit(ed?) the question. But before I submitted my question I was at risk to be blocked, so was to read!!!

Comment: In science it is generally expected that you do some research before making a claim, editorial articles are not research. there is a wonderful tool called google scholar that lets you search actual sources. https://scholar.google.com/

Comment: @john What can I do to improve my question? I've done it a zillion times now. Why can't I ask questions anymore? On which grounds has my privilege been taken away, though I think I know...

Answer (score 1):

> non-coding, information-rich, DNA

Since noncoding DNA contains many long repeating sequences repeated thousands or even millions of times, it is not necessarily information rich, and is often extremely low entropy.

> Does human DNA contain that much (the most) non-coding parts?

No. The human genome is a midsized genome by eukaryotic standards, so it's not going to contain the most of almost anything because it isn't large enough. To put into context, the wheat genome has ~6 times as much noncoding DNA as the entire human genome. Then there is the lungfish, which could fit as many again copies of the wheat genome into it's noncoding DNA:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5718017/#Sec1title

> Could it be that this huge amount is what makes us "free"? That thát's the reason why we differ from other species in an obvious way?

Our genomes are very average for eukaryotes, so not likely.

> Has there any research been done to answer my claim?

Yes. The puzzling lack of correlation between genome size and organism complexity was an unsolved mystery in biology for about half a century. It was eventually resolved when high throughput sequencing combines with bioinformatics revealed that the actual information required to build an organism is very low compared to the typical size of a genome, and so factors other than information content drive genome size.

Also as an aside since I saw this in the comments: since a BP can have 4 values, it can store 2 (not 1) bits of information. Most BPs store less however because they are not random.

Comment: What about the length of human DNA? In comparison to other species?

Comment: Each base pair is 0.34 nm long. 3 billion * 0.34nm = 1 m per copy and you have two copies. You can do the math for other species.